# Testing react-leaflet marker click event triggers `Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)`

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-leaflet

I want to test click events on a [react-leaftlet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) marker. I'm using `jest` alongside `testing-library` for the tests.

```
"react-leaflet": "^3.2.1"
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.15.1",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.0.0-beta.7",
```

Given the following `TestMarker` component that renders a map with a marker that calls the `onClick` prop when being clicked:

```js
import React from "react";

import { MapContainer, Marker, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

const TestMarker = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      style={{ height: "500px" }}
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      zoom={13}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker
        position={[51.505, -0.09]}
        eventHandlers={{ click: props.onClick }}
      />
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default TestMarker;
```

And the following test that renders `TestMarker`, selects the `img` tag of the marker and simulates a click event on it using [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/):

```js
import React from "react";

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import TestMarker from "./TestMarker";

test("triggers onClick prop on click (userEvent)", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  const onClick = jest.fn();
  render(<TestMarker onClick={onClick} />);
  const marker = screen.getAllByRole("img")[1];
  await user.click(marker);
  expect(onClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

The test fails with the following error message:

```
 ✕ triggers onClick prop on click (userEvent) (325 ms)

  ● triggers onClick prop on click (userEvent)

    Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)

      at new LatLng (node_modules/leaflet/src/geo/LatLng.js:32:9)
      at Object.unproject (node_modules/leaflet/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js:35:10)
      at Object.pointToLatLng (node_modules/leaflet/src/geo/crs/CRS.js:41:26)
      ...

  ● triggers onClick prop on click (userEvent)

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      25 |   const marker = screen.getAllByRole("img")[1];
      26 |   await user.click(marker);
    > 27 |   expect(onClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
         |                   ^
      28 | });
```

The same test using `fireEvent` instead of `userEvent` passes with no errors.

```js
test("triggers onClick prop on click (fireEvent)", () => {
  const onClick = jest.fn();
  render(<TestMarker onClick={onClick} />);
  const marker = screen.getAllByRole("img")[1];
  fireEvent.click(marker);
  expect(onClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

I have tried setting the container `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` as outlined [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4823) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57458580/react-leaflet-invalid-latlng-object-on-running-test-when-using-boundsoptions), but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too when I upgraded to Testing Library user-event v14.

It is a really bizarre error. It appears that the root cause is that when **leaflet** handles a click event (inside the Map.js `_fireDOMEvent` function), it fires a `preclick` event first, but it clones the event object using `Util.extend({}, e)`. But it turns out that in user-event v14, the event object that it fires is a `PointerEvent` that extends from `MouseEvent` which has the `clientX` and `clientY` getter properties. But leaflet's `Util.extend` function only copies the own properties, and so `clientX` and `clientY` become undefined. Then when it converts from those x/y coordinates into a `LatLng` it fails with the `(NaN, NaN)` error you saw.

I tried numerous ways to get around this. I tried mocking parts of Leaflet to change this behavior, but I couldn't get it to work.

In the end I did a hack where I intercept the `_fireDOMEvent` function, and I convert the user-event's event object into a proper web `MouseEvent`, that way when it gets cloned by Leaflet (in `Util.extend`) everything works.

It's not pretty... but seems to work for my unit tests. Here is a pseudo code snippet of what my React Leaflet unit test looks like - I have a custom render function for rendering any leaflet layer/marker/overlay:

```
function customRender(ui) {
  return render(ui, {
    wrapper: (props) => (
      <MapContainer center={L.latlng(50, 0)} zoom={15} {...props}>
        <FixMap />
        {children}
      </MapContainer>
    )
  });
}

function FixMap() {
  const map = useMap();
  useEffect(() => {
    const container = map.getContainer();
    // First leaflet container to have a fixed size
    if (container.clientWidth === 0) {
      Object.defineProperty(container, 'clientWidth', { value: 800 });
      Object.defineProperty(container, 'clientHeight', { value: 600 });
    }

    // Fix bug where Util.extend doesn't clone getters properly
    const realFireDOMEvent = map._fireDOMEvent;
    map._fireDOMEvent = (e, type, canvasTargets) => {
      if (type === 'click') {
        // the clientX and clientY getter properties are defined on the parent MouseEvent class
        // when leaflet clones the event object to fire the 'preclick' event
        // these properties are not copied and are therefore undefined
        const { target, currentTarget, srcElement } = e;
        e = new MouseEvent(type, {
          button: e.button,
          buttons: e.buttons,
          clientX: e.clientX,
          clientY: e.clientY,
          relatedTarget: e.target,
          screenX: e.screenX,
          screenY: e.screenY,
          altKey: e.altKey,
          ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
          shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
          metaKey: e.metaKey,
          detail: e.detail,
          view: e.view,
          bubbles: e.bubbles,
          cancelable: e.cancelable,
          composed: e.composed,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(e, 'target', { value: target, enumerable: true });
        Object.defineProperty(e, 'currentTarget', { value: currentTarget, enumerable: true });
        Object.defineProperty(e, 'srcElement', { value: srcElement, enumerable: true });
      }
      return realFireDOMEvent.call(map, e, type, canvasTargets);
    };
  }, [map]);
  return null;
}
```